# SQL UPDATE with PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I get this error while trying to update. The query works in phpmyadmin just fine.

Was a bind error, all fixed thanks to the great people here.

Comment: you might consider server side validation to make sure your POST variables meet basic criteria, such as not being empty ('').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've got typo in your parameters.

You are using `:serreceivetxt` instead of `:userreceivetxt` and `:serreceiveemail` instead of `:userreceiveemail`.

Comment: Wow 8 hours for that. LMAO I looked at it 30 times and did not see that.

Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!!

Comment: @GeorgeFischer this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have told you in 8 "seconds" ;-)